Morphism inducing isomorphism in homotopy category is weak equivalence
In Goerss-Jardine's book "Simplicial Homotopy Theory" they prove in Lemma 4.1 of chapter II that for a simplicial model category $\mathcal{C}$ the statement
$$\text{ If }f:X\to Y \text{ in } \mathcal{C}\text{ induces an isomorphism in }\mathcal{H}o(\mathcal{C}) \text{ then } f \text{ is a weak-equivalence}. \quad (1)$$
After the proof they write that the statement (1) was "probably the most important
technical consequence of having a simplicial model structure in hand, as opposed
to just a closed model structure. It will be used many times in the sequel. Here
is a sample application:..."
What confuses me is that apparently (1) is already true for any closed model category $\mathcal{C}$. This is Proposition 1.2.10 in Mark Hovey's "Model Categories".
My question is: Am I misunderstanding Goerss-Jardin or Hovey?

This is probably a matter of different definitions, maybe they mean by $\mathcal{Ho}(\mathcal{C})$ the homotopy category of the underlying model category, thus this would be a strong result because inducing an iso in this homotopy category would mean being a weak equivalence in the sSet-enriched category $\underline{\mathcal{C}}$. This looks like a generalization of the equivalence $f:X\to Y$ continuous is an homotopy equivalence (with topological homotopy) iff $f_*:C(X) \to C(Y)$ is a homotopy equivalence (with algebraic homotopy $(fg-1) = \partial s + s \partial)$.

@julio_es_sui_glace Both books are talking about weak equivalences in the closed model category $\mathcal{C}$, which in Goerss-Jardin's case is the underlying model category of the simplicial model category.

Ok thanks for the detail

We might have a different version of the book (mine is a 2009 ''reprint of the 1999 edition''), because I don't have a Lemma 4.1 to begin with. I do have Proposition 1.14, which states:
"Suppose that $f\colon X\to Y$ is a morphism of a closed model
category $C$ which induces an isomorphism in the homotopy category $\mathrm{Ho}(C)$. Then $f$ is a weak equivalence."
This is the same statement as in Hovey. There are many reasons why we like simplicial model categories, but this statement is not one of them and is in fact true much more generally, even for things that are not model categories but have other kinds of homotopical structure subject to axioms. This nlab article and a cycle of linked pages are about the link between saturation (which is the statement that weak equivalences are precisely the morphisms that become isomorphisms in the homotopy category), the 2-out-of-6 property and closure of weak equivalences under retracts, inside a ''category with homotopical structure''.
